# ng-checked is not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pug

I am facing a weird issue with `ng-checked`. I am applying it in my edit form to show selected option value but its not working. Following is my code and screen shot -

My controller code -

```
  if( true == $scope.employee.active ) {
    $scope.is_active_yes = true;
    $scope.is_active_no = false;
  }
  else {
    $scope.is_active_yes = false;
    $scope.is_active_no = true;
  }
});
```

Code in my Jade template -

```
.row
  .control-label.col-md-3 Is Active:
  .col-md-6
    input(type="radio", name="active", ng-model="employee.active", value="yes" ng-checked="{{is_active_yes}}")
    | Yes
    input(type="radio", name="active", ng-model="employee.active", value="no" ng-checked="{{is_active_no}}")
    | No
```

Though value is coming in my form for `ng-checked` but it is not applying to the markup. Let me know what I am doing wrong here ?

FYI - No error in the console and data is coming as you can check it in the screenshot.

[image: ng-checked]

Comment: It should be `ng-checked="is_active_yes"`

Comment: @CodeHater Oh wow ..yes it is the case..can you please tell me why it should not use `{{  }}` in this case, as I supposed to get values in jade template we need to add this

Comment: @CodeHater Please paste this as an answer..if possible with explanation as it solved my problem and I will accept it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ngChecked` directive works on [expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) and not on interpolated values. So don't wrap your expressions within `{{ }}`:

```
ng-checked="is_active_yes"
```

Comment: Its working fine but whenever I save the edit form its losing the values though other values remain on the form...let me know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Create a fiddle or share the related html and controller code.

Comment: It was my bad..actually I am saving the boolean values in mongo but I am having yes/no (String) declared values for radio...just changed them to true/false and all working fine...resolved...thx for the help :) and have a g8 day :)

Answer (score 1):

ng-checked is an Angular Attribute. Hence, it won't require {{ }} for interpolating the value of the scope variable you are passing. Hence you can directly use the variable name in the attribute as

```
ng-checked="is_active_yes"
```

Comment: Then why it not working if I adding `ng-checked="employee.active"` ? If I am using the above method for saving the edit form all values remain on the page, but I am loosing the scope for radio selection